# Injecting login page

Tags: php, sql, authentication, sql-injection

I am trying to Inject this but I did not know please guide me to the right method.

```
<?php

$dh='localhost';
$du='root';
$dp='';
$dbn='login';
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$co=new mysqli($dh,$du,$dp,$dbn);

echo "<br>";

$result="select * from users  ";

$res=mysqli_query($co,$result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
if($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
    echo "login success!!! Welcome ".$row['username'];
}else{
    echo "Failed to login!";
}
?>
```

I have tried to use this  `") or true--` but did not work!

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by Inject? Do you mean you are testing SQL Injection?

Comment: "insject" what? Where? Are you talking about doing a _database insert_?

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson strictly speaking, this particular code is not injectable ;)

Comment: @YourCommonSense - That's why I added _"Well, you would be if you actually used the data"_ :-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes SQL Injection

Comment: This code would only ever work if you had only one user!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Any idea how to make it Injectable ?

Comment: You need to use the variables in your query to start with.

Comment: Normally we try Very Hard to make in NOT Injectable

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir, I am not trying to make it secure I am trying to perform SQL Injection. Any idae how to inject it?!

Comment: Injectable `$result="select * from users WHERE username = '$username'";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly what should I input in the username and password filed?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have only one user

Comment: If it's an exercise in SQL injection, why not input good ol' [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) (just change "students" to "users")? :)

Comment: @El_Vanja I did not get you. Could you please explain more?!!

Comment: @YourCommonSense For learning purpose :)

Answer (score -2):

There are some issues in this code, but an SQL injection is not one of them since the SQL query doesn't include any dynamic data.

It would be if the sql query used the params coming from the request :

```
$result="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}'";
```

Comment: Still showing Failed to login! when I try to Inject it using this  ") or true--

Comment: You asked for something to guide you, not to resolve it all together. You need to figure  the variables $username and $password that can be used to make the above query to always return a result.

Comment: Thanks anyway sir